# synchronization web service methodologies or papers

Tags: php, iphone, web-services, json, synchronization

I asked this question on [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/94634/synchronization-web-service-methodologies-or-papers), but it has been crickets for a day... if this is the wrong place, I will just kill the question.

I am building a web service (PHP+JSON) to sync with my iphone app. The main goals are:

1. Backup
2. Provide a web view for printing / sorting, manipulating.
3. allow a group sync up and down.

I am aware of the logic problems with all of these items, Ie. if one person deletes something, do you persist this change to other users, collisions, etc.

I am looking for just any book or scholarly work, or even words of wisdom to address common issues.

- when to detect changes of data with hashes, vs modified dates, or combination.
- how do address consolidation of sequential ID's originating on different client nodes (can be sidestepped in my context, but it would be interesting.)
- dealing with collisions (is there a universally safe way to do so?).
- general best practices.
- how to structure the actual data transaction (ask for whole list then detect changes...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the slides of a presentation that's been given at ZendCon 2009<sup>1</sup>, which should give you some ideas : [**Planning for Synchronization with Browser-Local Databases**](http://www.slideshare.net/ZendCon/planning-for-synchronization-with-browserlocal-databases)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If I'm not mistaken</sub>

Comment: tray bee-in mon frare (I speak french like I spell it) this is the type of thing I am after.

Comment: If meant meant "very well, brother", it would be written "très bien, mon frère" ^^ ; well, glad I could help :-)